# Algorithm to find max cost path of length N in matrix, from [0,0] to last row

Tags: performance, algorithm, matrix

I have a `n*n` matrix, where each element represents an integer. Starting in `[0,0]` I have to find the path of exactly `m` elements down to the last row, returning the maximum cost. The path can end in any column on the last row and `n ≤ m ≤ n^2`

I thought of finding all paths of length `m` from `[0,0]` to `[n-1, 0], [n-1, 1] ... [n-1, n-1]`. But it does not feel optimal...

Which algorithm would be the most efficient way of doing this? BFS or DFS?

**EDIT**

Possible directions are down/right/left, but only visit each element at most once.

**EDIT 2**

So for example, if this matrix is given (n=4):

```
[   1   4   1  20 ]
[   5   0   2   8 ]
[   6   8   3   8 ]
[   3   2   9   5 ]
```

And m=7, the path could be

```
[   →   →   →   ↓ ]
[   5   0   2   ↓ ]
[   6   8   3   ↓ ]
[   3   2   9   x ] = Path cost = 47
```

or

```
[   ↓   4   1  20 ]
[   ↓   0   2   8 ]
[   →   →   ↓   8 ]
[   3   2   →   x ] = Path cost = 32
```

or if `m = n^2`

```
[   →   →   →   ↓ ]
[   ↓   ←   ←   ← ]
[   →   →   →   ↓ ]
[   x   ←   ←   ← ]
```

**EDIT 3 / SOLUTION**

Thanks to Wanderley Guimarães,
http://ideone.com/0iLS2

Comment: Can you "go back" (or only right/down?) Are there negative integers?

Comment: Only down/left/right, can only visit each element at most 1 time. Only positive integers aswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem with dynamic programming. Let `value(i, j)` the value from position `(i, j)` of your matrix (i-th line, j-th column).

```
if i <  0 then f(i, j) = 0
if i == 0 then f(i, j) = value(i, j)
if i >  0 then f(i, j) = max(f(i-1, j), f(i, j-1)) + value(i, j)
```

That recurrence assume that you use a position from your matrix when you step down. So, you answer is `max(f(m, 0), f(m-1, 1), f(m - 2, 2), ..., f(1, m))`.

For example:

Give the follow matrix for `n = 4`:

```
1 1 1 1
1 2 1 1
2 1 1 1
1 2 1 1
```

If `m = 2` then you cant go after second line. And you answer is `f(2, 2) = 4`.

If `m = 4` then you cant go after third line. And you answer is `f(3, 2) = 5`.

*(Im learning english so If you didnt understand something let me know and I will try to improve my explanation).*

**Edit :: allow down/left/right moves**

You can implement follow recurrence:

```
if i == n, j == n, p == m, j == 0 then f(i, j, p, d) = 0
if d == DOWN  then f(i, j, p, d) = max(f(i+1, j, p+1, DOWN), f(i, j-1, p+1, RIGHT),   f(i, j+1, p+1,LEFT)) + value(i, j)
if d == LEFT  then f(i, j, p, d) = max(f(i+1, j, p+1, DOWN), f(i, j+1, p+1, LEFT )) + value(i, j)
if d == RIGHT then f(i, j, p, d) = max(f(i+1, j, p+1, DOWN), f(i, j-1, p+1, RIGHT)) + value(i, j)
```

This solution is `O(n^4)`. *Im trying to improve it.*

You can test it at http://ideone.com/tbH1j

Comment: Note that this solution as well fails for the specific problem at hand since you can move left as well as right.

Comment: Note that `m ≥ n`, and one must always finish on the last row. Thus, if m=4 (number of visisted elements), the only path possible is [0,0]->[1,0]->[2,0]->[3,0] giving path cost of 5

Comment: @hakanito: Your claim is true only if you assume `m <= 2n`. However, this is not the case - you assume `m <=n^2` - you can make a complete "swap" of the matrix with m=n^2. I added a counter example that shows this issue in my answer, have a look.

Comment: `max(f(i-1, j), f(i-1, j))` ?? This doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @hakanito I think that I fixed my solution.

Comment: @WanderleyGuimarães nice work on the code, but I don't think it is fully working.

Comment: @WanderleyGuimarães I modified your solution, now it is working :) http://ideone.com/0iLS2

Comment: What if there is a condition that each cell only visited once and if it is visited more than once, from the second time onwards its value should be considered as 0.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is very known. The most efficient way of doing this is dynamic programming.

Let `dp[i][j]` is the maximum sum when coming to i,j from 0,0.
Then, `dp[i][j] = max(dp[i - 1][j], dp[i][j - 1]) + matrix[i][j]`;

After doing this, check every value of position where you are able to go and get the maximum value.

Comment: You are of course right that dynamic programming is the way to go. But how do I restrict the path to a specific length?

Comment: Well, you get maximum of elements where `i + j == m` or something.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a DAG, and therefore the dynamic programming solution to the longest path problem works.

Why a DAG, you say? There is an obvious cycle going from two vertices that are horizontally adjacent. If you use the "obvious" graph, of course.

The less obvious approach is to rework this as a graph of (vertex, direction), in which direction is the last direction you took from down/left/right. A vertex that has direction down can go either down, left, or right, whereas a vertex with direction right can only go down/right, and a vertex with direction left can only go left/down. This graph is clearly acyclic, and it comprises all possible paths in the original matrix.

Therefore, ignoring the limit `m`, a possible recursion for the longest path to (a, b, direction) is

```
pdl[i][j] = max(pdl[i][j-1], pd[i-1][j])+arr[i][j];
pdr[i][j] = max(pdr[i][j+1], pd[i-1][j])+arr[i][j];
pd[i][j] = max(pdl[i][j], pdr[i][j]);
```

`pd` is the array for the "down" vertices, `pdr` for right and `pdl` is for left. As an implementation detail, note that I  keep the max of the left and corresponding down vertex in `pdl`, but this doesn't really matter as any vertex with direction "down" can go  left and down just as a "left" vertex would. Same for `pdr`.

The limit means you'll have to add another dimension to that DP solution, that is, you have to keep `pd[i][j][moves]`, that keeps the highest sum possible until vertex (i, j) using exactly `moves` movements, obtaining the recursion

```
pdl[i][j][moves] = max(pdl[i][j-1][moves-1], pd[i-1][j][moves-1])+arr[i][j];
pdr[i][j][moves] = max(pdr[i][j+1][moves-1], pd[i-1][j][moves-1])+arr[i][j];
pd[i][j][moves] = max(pdl[i][j][moves-1], pdr[i][j][moves-1]);
```

Comment: The algorithm above is in C++, how could pseudo-code be any better? (I honestly don't know what else I could say in a pseudocode snippet.)

Comment: No you are right, but your algorithm looked different than the one proposed by Wanderely. So I thought you perhaps could elaborate in psuedocode. Also, the C++ code does not work, I get the wrong answer in different test cases

Answer (score 1):

This Question can be solved using recursion and backtracking. Keep the count of steps covered till now and the cost of path till now.

Here is my implementation    https://ideone.com/N6T55p

```
void fun_me(int arr[4][4], int m, int n,int i,int j,int steps,int cost)
{

//cout<<steps<<endl;
if(i>=n || j>=n)
    return;
visited[i][j]=1;
if(i==n-1 && steps==m-1)
{
    if(maxer<arr[i][j]+cost)
        maxer=arr[i][j]+cost;
    //cout<<arr[i][j]+cost<<endl;
}

if(isvalid(i+1,j,n) && !visited[i+1][j])
    fun_me(arr,m,n,i+1,j,steps+1,cost+arr[i][j]);

if(isvalid(i,j+1,n) && !visited[i][j+1])
    fun_me(arr,m,n,i,j+1,steps+1,cost+arr[i][j]);

if(isvalid(i,j-1,n) && !visited[i][j-1])
    fun_me(arr,m,n,i,j-1,steps+1,cost+arr[i][j]);

visited[i][j]=0;
return ;
}
```