# Analyzing time-complexity of heaviest path in a NxN matrix utilizing memoization

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

What is the time-complexity of the the algorithm (in pseudo-code) below? I have had a hard time analyzing it. It is an implementation of the problem specified at another thread: [Algorithm to find max cost path of length N in matrix, from [0,0] to last row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12744424/1009831). But because I'm new here I don't have points enough to comment in the thread (I think)?. This is my first post, so excuse me if i did something wrong.

The algorithm uses memoization with the `cache[][][][]`. During the initialization `cache[][][][]` is filled with -1.

The method is called with `maxPath(0,0,m,DOWN)`. Where m is the amount of steps to take, n<=m<=n^2 and the directions are defined as DOWN=0, LEFT=1, RIGHT=2.

```
function maxPath(i, j, fuel, direction)
    if i = n OR j = n OR j < 0 OR fuel = 0 then
         return 0;
    end if
    if cache[i][j][f-1][d] != -1 then
         return cache[i][j][f - 1][d];
    end if
    ret := 0
    acc+ = matrix[i][j]
    ret:=max(ret,maxPath(i+1, j, fuel-1, DOWN))
    if f > n - i then . If there is enough steps to move horizontally
        if d = RIGHT or d = DOWN then
            ret:=max(ret,maxPath(i, j+1, fuel-1, RIGHT))
        end if
        if d = LEFT or d = DOWN then
            ret:=max(ret,maxPath(i, j-1, fuel-1, LEFT))
        end if
    end if
    return cache[i,j,fuel-1,direction] = ret + matrix[i][j]
end function
```

Comment: fuel? harvest? this isn't for a farmville bot, is it?

Comment: It is obviousely O(3^n) if we don't use memoization

Comment: @Desolator yes that much I understand. However with the memoization the timecomplexity is reduced, but I'm not sure how much.

Comment: @Marc B, thank you for pointing those things out, I have edited my post to make it more general now. (it is not for farmville)

Comment: With memoization I did alot of test with wolfram-alpha and did see that the amount of recursive calls grows with O(m*n^2). Where m=n*n^p where 0<=p<=1 so that n<=m=<n^2. However I have no way to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey I have solved it and was thinking that I should share my results.

If we let G=(V,E) be a graph where V={maxPath(i, j, p, d) : for all possible i, j, p and d } and E= {uv : u = f(i, j, p, d) and v = f(i', j', p', d') }. We have that G is a graph of states which is clearly DAG (directed acyclic graph). Then, we can compute maxPath with memoization.

We have

```
    n possible values for i
    n possible values for j
    m possible values for fuel (which in worst case is n^2)
    3 possible values for direction
```

Then we have n * n * m * 3 differents functions of maxPath to be called which is n^4*3 in worst case. So, we have O(n^4) different functions. Each call of function runs in O(1) time. Because the graph has a suboptimal structure, each subproblem is problem of the original one. So with memoization we dont have to compute the same 'function' two times, thus we get O(n^4).