# Path of length up to k with max value

Tags: algorithm, graph, max, longest-path

I currently work on a problem where I want to try to find an algorithm which does the following: Given a square grid graph G and start node S and an end node E, where E and S in G, find a path P from S to E with maximum value and |P| <= k. If it makes it easier, one can possibly make G a DAG.

The grid cells are either 0 or 1.

**As an example:**

```
S--o--o--o
|  :  |  |
o--o..o..o
:  |  :  |
o--o--E--o
|  :  |  |
o--o--o--o

S := "Starting State" 
E := "Ending State" 
- := "Edge value is 1" 
. := "Edge value is 0"
```

**Solution with k = 5 (from what I see)**

```
S  o  o  o
|         
o--o  o  o
   |     
o  o--E  o

o  o  o  o
```

S and E lie arbitrarily, so one cannot assume just down  and right movement, but I can transform the graph to a DAG with some loss to optimality I assume.

Edge value is a cost, G is a grid graph where every node is connected to its four neighbours.

First of all, is this problem already known in literature? I did not find anything about it. Is it in NP or does someone has an idea for a fast algorithm? I asked the search engine of my choice, and somebody asked something maybe related to it on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744424/algorithm-to-find-max-cost-path-of-length-n-in-matrix-from-0-0-to-last-row%20SO) , but their problem description does not match 100%, since their goal is last row, where mine is a distinct node.

Comment: Can we assume down/right as drawn, or may the end be in any direction?

Comment: Astar? is the edge values a cost, or does it mean that its no edge there?

Comment: I updated the Q to answer your comments. Does A* also work for longest path with my given additions?

Comment: if k is not big, you can use Bellman-Ford, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Aight, a warning first: I've thought this up on the spur of the moment. I seem to remember reading about something like it before, but I can't remember where, so while it seems correct I can't be sure of it. If I spot a flaw later, I'll come back and edit this post and notify you.

Let *L(k, v)* be the value of the path of length at most *k* from *S* to some node *v*, and suppose *v* has predecessors *{u1, u2, ... um}*. Since *G* is a DAG, it must be that

```
L(k, v) = max { L(k-1, u1) + w(u1, v), L(k-1, u2) + w(u2, v), ..., L(k-1, um) + w(um, v) }
```

where *w(u,v)* is the weight of the edge from *u* to *v*.

To put this to use, what we're going to do is find the highest value path of length *< R* to every node within a radius of *R* of *S*. That then gives us enough information to calculate the highest-value path of length *< R+1* to every node within a radius *R+1* of *S*. So:

1. First, throw away any node that is more than distance *k* from *S*, as it can't possibly be part of the optimum path. We have *O(k^2)* nodes remaining.
2. Now initialize a collection `L` and set `L[S] = 0`. Leave all other entries undefined.
3. Next, apply the `L[v]` rule to each node in the graph (ignore the `k` parameters)

   - If a predecessor *u* of a node *v* doesn't have a value for `L[u]` defined yet, ignore *u* when calculating `L[v]`.
   - If *no* predecessor *u* of *v* has `L[u]` defined, leave `L[v]` undefined.
4. Repeat Step 3 *k-1* more times.
5. If `L[E]` has a value, return it. Else there is no length `k` path from *S* to *E*.

This is *O(k^3)* time. You could probably speed it up for large graphs by only considering nodes both within distance 1 of *S* and distance *k-1* of *E* during the first execution of Step 3, and only nodes within distance 2 of *S* and distance *k-2* of *E* during the second execution, and so-on, but that'll still be cubic time.