# An interesting maze

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, dynamic-programming

We have a maze R X C where 1<=R,C<=500. This maze is filled by numbers from -1 to 100. Now , the game is as follows :

> Where ever there is -1 in square , assume that is a stone block in
>   that cell and you cannot move throught that cell. You can begin from
>   any cell on 1st column (of course that does not have -1) and exit from
>   any cell from last column . You can move either up , down , right. As
>   you move , u collect the numbers in the cell except -1 which denote a
>   big stone is placed in our maze. Each cell has to be visited once
>   only.

What is the path from left to right where you can select maximum sum of numbers ? EASY !! Dp can do magic But But ... here's the catch — Rule 5 .

> We can move out of maze if we can reach first or bottom row. But then
>   2 things happen :
>
> a) We lose all points collected till now.
>
> b) we renter the maze in the same column but in the opposite cell.

ex: consider 3X3 maze (1 -indexed) . so if we reach say , (1,2) we can exit from there and lose all points and enter (3,2) , and game continues ....

Now , we have to find the path with maxiumum score.

I am unable to see how would we capture this jumping out and back in maze by dynamic programming ?  Also , we have to make score '0' each time we do it .

Example  :

consider the maze :

```
-1  4  5  1
 2 -1  2  4
 3  3 -1 -1
 4  2  1  2
```

answer  =16 .

(4,1)  -> (4,2) -> (1,2)  -> (1,3) -> (2,3) -> (2,4) -> (1,4)

Comment: what does "we have to make score '0' each time we do it " mean?

Comment: @ergonaut , in the example above :  (4,2) -> (1,2) makes us lose all points collected  and hence when we reach (1,2) our score is '0'. Otherwise , if we consider only (4,1) -> (4,2) we would have score of (4+2) =6 .

Comment: it would help if you formatted your maze.

Comment: I don't see how "rule 5" hinders your general DP approach. Just add a condition to handle that case.

Comment: Ya , forgot that in a hurry to edit example .

Comment: I still don't see how you get 16.  When you reenter, I only add up to 14.

Comment: V ery similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621337/java-maximum-sum-in-path-through-a-2d-array and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744424/algorithm-to-find-max-cost-path-of-length-n-in-matrix-from-0-0-to-last-row

Comment: @ergonaut , began from (1,2) as path mentioned above = 4 +5+2 + 4+1  =16

Comment: what is (4,1) -> (4,2) -> (1,2) -> (1,3) -> (2,3) -> (2,4) -> (1,4) then??

Comment: These are the coordinates of cell of maze. The sequence denote path.

Comment: I think the correct answer to this example will be 21.  (4,1) -> (4,2) -> (3,2) -> (2,3) ->(1,3) -> (1,4) -> (2,4)

Comment: I know it's been a long time since you asked this question but if possible, can you post the link to this question on some OJ? I want to check if my solution is correct by submitting it.

Comment: @vish4071: (3,2) -> (2,3) is a diagonal move, which doesn't seem to be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Run the same DP algorithm you had. After you finish a column check if the top/lower positions are accessible (there's a path to get there and they aren't blocked).

If one is accessible and the other isn't the assume you can get to the inaccessible one with previous score 0 (basically run the computation again but assume the cell on the previous column has score 0).

If none are accessible then there's nothing to do.

If both are accessible, since you have positive score everywhere it makes no sense do drop something >0 and start with 0 again.

Comment: its not just dp . I have to consider accesibility from 1st column to those border cells of 1st and last row as there are stone blocks in b/t blocking our way . Then only i can decide if some cell giving maximum answer have to be considered or not . How to capture this whole ?

Comment: Each cell should contain a number >0 if it's accessible in some way from the first column or -1 if it's blocked or there's no way to get to that cell. So you don't need to consider if there's a path, it will be encoded in the answer(if all cells on the last column are -1 after your dp, there's no path).

Comment: is possible , pls present a pseudo code + base conditions for i m not getting it.

Comment: Sure, show me what you have and I'll tell you what you need to add.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to obtain a list of solutions (without going through -1) from

```
A) Left -> Right
B) Top -> Right
C) Bottom -> Right
```

Then you should also be able to get a list of paths from (without -1)

```
D) Left -> Top
E) Left -> Bottom
```

From the list (B) remove any which do not have a connecting path from list (D). 
From the list (C) remove any which do not have a connecting path from list (E).

Then pick the highest solution from A, B, C.